# Discord.js load balancing multible responses

Tags: node.js, discord.js, load-balancing, pm2

ive a bot that has high usage
so when i try to use something like pm2 for clustering "let's say `pm2 start task.js i- 4`"
the bot response 4 times

is there a way to fix this
what is the easiest way to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sharding](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ShardingManager). It'll split your bot up and assign some number of guilds to each, so each part of the bot will only see messages from some of the guilds, and no bot instances share guilds.

Keep in mind that it might take some effort to set up sharding, and isn't as straightforward as just setting up a sharding manager (unless your bot is simple). Also, here's a tutorial on it: [https://discordjs.guide/sharding](https://discordjs.guide/sharding/).